# How to handle imbalanced data in general

Tags: machine-learning, data-science, imbalanced-data

I have been working on the case study where data is highly imbalanced. we have been taught we can handle the imbalanced data by either under sampling the majority class or over sampling the minority class.
I wanted to ask if there is any other way/method that can be used to handle imbalanced data?

this question is more on conceptual side than programming.

for example,
I was thinking if we could put some weight on minority class (conceptually) to make the model emphasize on identifying pattern in minority class.
I don't know how that can be done but this concept theoretically should work.

feel free to put crazy ideas too.

Answer (score 0):

Your weights idea is not far off. This can be done. In fact, most sklearn Models give you the option to specify class weights. This however is often not enough for very extreme cases (e.g. 95%/5% split or more extreme).

There are specific oversampling techniques such as SMOTE (and related techniques) which go a step further than classic oversampling and generate synthetic samples based on a K Nearest Neighbors Algorithm.

If the classes are extremely imbalanced a "classic" classification approach may not be enough and you might have to look into anomaly detection algorithms.

Answer (score 0):

Just use strong consistent classifier. See https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08528

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking I think that you need, before diving into the technical solution (under/upsampling, smote ..) consider the business KPI you are predicting and whether there is a proxy that could help reduce the disparity rate between the classes.

You can think also about the models that have weights parameters and could penalize the majority class

You can check [this article](https://medium.com/@kaislar17/data-science-how-to-deal-with-imbalanced-data-in-real-business-cases-fd68cae89979), it explains from a conceptual point of view how to deal with imbalanced data in general.

Answer (score 0):

There are many options:

- Using different weights for the different classes.
- Using a cost matrix.
- Using metrics robust to imbalance, for example the MCC coefficient or AUC PR.
- Modifying the threshold used to decide the class. (Instead of P=0.5).